# Driving an inductive load with optocoupler+MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, opto-isolator

Is there anything missing/wrong with this schematic? I'm interested more specifically in additional protection that should be added, such as zeners, TVS diodes and so on.

Load is inductive, 12V, 0.5-1A, no PWM. The MCU is 5V.

Q1 will be something like [IRLB8726](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlr8726pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153567181dd26f7) or [IRLB8721](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlb8721pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153566056732591) or similar (depends on local supply).

**EDIT** (based on comments):
I'm just starting to learn about transistors, so there are a lot of "unknown unknowns" for me. In a sense I don't even know what I should be protecting from (except inductive kickback). But I don't mind spending $1-2 if there is some best practice that should be followed.

If I'm understanding the comments correctly, the tradeoff for R2 is faster gate discharge versus larger current when Q1 is "ON". What I don't understand is, is a bigger value undesirable because it will also load the optocoupler more? In this case I would lower it, because in this circuit the optocoupler is probably the component which is most likely to fail.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Hard to know given the limited information- What are you trying to protect against? For example, could the 12 V supply have spikes on it that exceed Q1's rating? Is the MCU located on a different board with long wires to the opto? Do you have to protect against various things possibly being short-circuited?

Comment: Such drive will have extremly slow turn off (gate discharge through 220+4k7). Depends on application if it can cause a problem.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický I thought the discharge is 220 in parallel with 47k ≈ 220?

Comment: They are in series.

Comment: You are right, I see. Can this be fixed by changing the topology, or should I decrease the value of R2?

Comment: Both options are possible. However if you decrese 47k to much lower value you will increase a power consumption.

Comment: Now i read it is not going about pwm so don’t bother with driving speed. Holding mosfet in linear a little during turn off is even advantage avoiding high voltage spike on drain.

Comment: Put R2 between R3 and the gate. R2 shouldn't be less than 10K for power consumption. 22K is a good value but 47K too, IMO. The R3 can be 1K or more, which will protect the gate even better.

Comment: I would decrease R2 to 10k anyway, or maybe 4.7k depending on opto grade, just to give a better on/off ratio, immunity to leakage, that sort of thing. As mentioned, further protective features depend on what you're doing with it; would UVLO be a concern? Overcurrent, limiting, or fusing? What is the supply voltage range including transients? Are there any standards that might be relevant, e.g. for 12V from an automotive source, ISO-7637 and similar?

Comment: What is D1 used for?

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't have the knowledge to understand what you mean by "better on/off ratio, immunity to leakage", can you elaborate? I edited the original post.

Comment: Compare LED forward/on current * CTR, versus max "dark" or leakage current in the opto.

Comment: With 1.4V drop and 50% CTR - 3mA vs 100nA. If the opto output is like a current source, higher R2 leads to higher voltage drop, is this the problem?